# Batch file CSV string to pyramid

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, dos

I am working on one of the batch file and I have a specific requirement where I have a string **"text1,text2,text3,text4...etc"** & I would like to have my output as a pyramid like

**text1  

text1,text2  

text1,text2,text3  

text1,text2,text3,text4  

..etc**

My brain says that it is easily achievable, but not getting the logic! How could I do it through batch scripting (for loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method below allows you to have a list of comma-separated values that may contain spaces or Batch special characters. Of course, it also works with your simple values.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=text one,text <two>,text |three|,text &four&"
set "line="
for %%a in ("%string:,=","%") do (
   set "line=!line!%%~a,"
   echo !line:~0,-1!
)
```

Output:

```
text one
text one,text <two>
text one,text <two>,text |three|
text one,text <two>,text |three|,text &four&
```

Comment: Fantastic. It works great. I like your solution as it can deal with special chars as well. Much appreciated!

Comment: Just note that this method fail with wild-card characters, that is, `*` and `?`

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "text=text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7,text8"
    set "output="

    for %%a in (%text%) do (
        if defined output ( set "output=!output!,%%a" ) else set "output=%%a"
        echo(!output!
    )
```

As the values are separated with commas, and commas are a default delimiter in `for` command, just iterate over the list concatenating the values as they are processed

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a variable in which on every loop, you'd append a text on it. You'll also need activate `delayedexpansion` so your variables get updated quick. `for /l %%a in (;;)` creates an infinite loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=text1
for /l %%a in (;;) do (
    echo !var!
    set var=!var!,text1
)
```

Edit: Noticed that your numbers actually increment. You can do:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=text1
for /l %%a in (2,1,100) do (
    echo !var!
    set var=!var!,text%%a
)
```

- 2   = initial value of `%%a`
- 1   = increment per loop
- 100 = maximum number but only with respect to condition. max number printed is 100 - 1 or 99.

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox but text1,text2,text3 were just examples and my case was actually dealing with different strings. Nevertheless a good answer and I am sure I will use this logic somewhere else.